# How to get the published posts in laravel using corcel?

Tags: database, wordpress, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am trying to use corcel to retrieve data from wordpress in laravel.

if i use like this, it show the error like this

```
$posts = \App\Post::published()->get();
return $posts;
```

> BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2451: Call to undefined
>   method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::published()

But if i use like this

```
 $posts = \App\Post::all();
 return $posts;`
```

it **works**.Help me out where am i missing to do.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you add this to your post model? `use Corcel\Post as Corcel;`

Comment: yes @Christophvh , i added it. like this <?php

namespace App;
use Corcel\Post as Corcel;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'wordpress';
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are still extending the Laravel model instead of Corcel. Since the published() method is defined in Corcel instead of Model you get that error.

Your Post class should look like this: (from the docs)

```
<?php // File: app/Post.php

namespace App;

use Corcel\Post as Corcel;

class Post extends Corcel //this should be Corcel and not Model
{
    protected $connection = 'wordpress';
}
```